# Latest ionic version : error "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds"

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed the latest version of ionic with:

> ionic start myApp tabs

After I launch these commands:

> ionic platform add ios
>
> ionic run ios

In the console, this message appear:

> deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds

And my code is never call:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```